# How to use two isset condition in single page

Tags: php, ajax, post, http-post

How do you use two `isset()` conditions in same page?

This is how my code looks:

```
    if (isset($_POST["location_from"]) && !empty($_POST["location_from"]))
    {

        .........
        .........
        echo json_encode($returnValues);        
    }
    if (isset($_POST["location_to"]) && !empty($_POST["location_to"]))
    {

           .........
           .........
            echo $value;
    }
  if (isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"]))
    {

           .........
           .........
            echo $value_Id;
    }
```

So in the above code when pass value in ajax `$_POST['location_from']` it works perfectly, and when pass value in ajax `$_GET['ID']` it works perfectly, BUT when pass value in ajax `$_POST['location_TO']` function inside `$_POST['location_from ']` also working and echoing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ... and where is problem? When you nest conditions and both are true, both echo are written.

Comment: actually when location_to come i need to echo  $value; only but it echoing  json_encode($returnValues);  too  this values also !!!!

Comment: So use `elseif`s instead of `if`s.

Comment: again am getting same error..!! when i pass location_to the echo json_encode($returnValues);   echoing .. !!

Comment: put first `location_to`, then `_from` as I wrote inn answer below. You shoud study how `if-elseif-else` condition works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write max 1 value (the first condition which is met), use `elseif`s instead of `if`s.

```
if (!empty($_POST['location_to'])) {
    echo ...;
} elseif (!empty($_POST['location_from'])) {
    echo ...;
} elseif (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    echo ...;
}
```